# Calculate distance of MKPolyline path?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, path

I would like to get the meters of a MKPolyline path so I can tell the user what are the meters left to finish the path.

I've been searching for something to do it but I couldn't get anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tedious as it sounds, unless you want to do the maths yourself you're probably going to have to iterate thought the line's `points`, convert each to a `CLLocation` and use its `-distanceFromLocation:` between each, summing up to the appropriate total.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering, that was what I was thinking about. Not a bad idea but it sounds scary ;) If there is no other solution I will do that.